# How do you set a CommandBinding on a TreeViewItem in a DataBound TreeView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, commandbinding

To simplify the issue I'm having, consider this hypothetical scenario.

In the XAML for my control, I have defined a `TreeView` and two fixed root `TreeViewItem` nodes, 'AItemsNode' and 'BItemsNode'.  In its ViewModel, I expose two child collections: AItems and BItems.  I then bind each root node's ItemsSource property to the respective collection on the ViewModel.  This works great and displays exactly what I want.

Now what I'd like to do is add a CommandBinding for ApplicationCommands.Open to the *child* TreeViewItem nodes of the two root nodes. Specifically I want the children under the root 'AItemsNode' to have their 'Open' CommandBinding point to 'OpenAItem_Executed' and children of the second root node to point theirs at 'OpenBItem_Executed'.

The issue I'm having is I don't know how to set the CommandBindings on the TreeViewItem objects themselves. I can't figure this out at all via XAML, and if I were to do it in the code-behind, I'd have to integrate with the ItemContainerGenerator, inspect what's being generated and add the bindings, essentially writing so much code I may as well add the 'Open' CommandBinding to the TreeView itself and inspect the SelectedObject and go from there.  Not optimal as I now have a single Open_Executed handler that delegates all over the place based on data type, but it does work!

Still, I'm hoping someone can show me how to add a CommandBinding directly to a generated TreeViewItem to avoid that and segregate out the code much more cleanly.

So... how can one apply specific CommandBindings via a style (or any other way in XAML) for a TreeViewItem?

Answer (score 0):

I take that you havent implemented `MVVM` (which would have intuitively solved this issue for you by making use of `RelayCommands` / `DelegateCommands` instead of `RoutedCommands`)

However in your case, you need to handle the `Initialized` event of `TreeViewItem` via `Style` targetted to `TreeViewItem`. Use `EventSetter` in the `Style`. And put your code that adds the `CommandBinding` to the `e.OriginalSource` value (which is the `TreeViewItem` itself that is getting initialized) incoming to the `TreeViewItem.Initialized` event handler.

Let me know if this makses sense.

**EDIT**

I understand that your have x number keyborad shortcuts for x number of distinct `TreeViewItems`. If so x number of styles make sense to me.

But if you want to do this cluttered in a single handler at the tree view level, then may be you would have to handle an attached event at that level ... I dont think `Initialised` / `Loaded` events bubble from indv treeviewitem all the way to the parent tree view, but it would be interesting to check that and I would be happy to have proved wrong!

Plus this would potentially not work for collapsed tree view items.

So suppose you define "Ctrl + o" shortcut for a specific tree view item which is within a collapsed tree branch or is it in the opened branch however it is outside the scroll view, the routed event based mechanisms (and thus command bindings) woudnt work because they need the item to be devirtualised (in UI memory) for routing to work ...

So my solution (as I understand now) becomes a little impractical in that case.

**Solution**

What is visible all the time?

TreeView!

So use that to your advantage. Add all command bindings (and shortcuts) to the TreeView itself!

And within the handler (which could be common across all command bindings) devise a mechanism to identify the individual item using a `ItemsSource` of `TreeViewItemViewModels` by searching within them and then inside the relevant `TreeViewItemViewModel` have mechanism to `Open` the `branch hierarchy` by Binding `IsOpen` property (INotifyable) to the `IsExpanded` property of the `TreeViewItem` via a generic style.

Comment: It (Relay/Delegate Commands) actually doesn't (to me). Can you explain how you would do this? And remember, a command can be triggered from its keyboard shortcut so the TreeViewItem is where the command 'starts' from.

Comment: Also, by your second suggestion, it seems like I would have to define 'x' number of styles (one per TreeViewNode-type that I wanted the event on), with 'x' number of handlers where I would wire up the CommandBindings to, which at that point, wouldn't it be much simpler to just define the binding at the TreeView and sort it out in the command handler? ...or am I missing something there too? Perhaps if you updated your answer with code it would help.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking the same language here. There are not 'x' commands.  Let me simplify it more.  Consider a TreeView with three statically-defined root nodes (i.e. defined in XAML): RootNodeA, RootNodeB and RootNodeC, with their ItemsSources pointing to AItems, BItems and CItems.  I want the standard ApplicationCommands.Delete command to map to 'DeleteAItem_Executed' *only for children of RootNodeA!!*  If RootNodeA is selected directly, then nothing happens as DeleteAItem_CanExecute would return false.  I want the same for RootNodeB and RootNodeC. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: If I mapped the Delete command to the TreeView itself, then I have to write a if/case switch to inspect the selected object, then branch to the individual CanExecute/Execute commands.  If we added a RootNodeD, then we'd have to modify that code-behind again.  If we however can map the bindings directly to the TreeViewItems via a XAML template, then we can simply swap in new resources to map new things up without having to recompile anything.  That makes the UI more extensible and data-driven.  Hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: By the way, the solution we came up with was to add a new attached property called CommandBindingsToAdd, and we apply that via a style.  Then in the attached property's change handler, we loop through the passed-in values and add them to the target object's CommandBindings property.  It works, but required us to create this as an attached behavior.  We feel this should be something you should be able to set directly in XAML.  Alas, that's apparently not the case.  As I said, hope this all makes sense now.

Comment: One other thing... Just an FYI, nodes that are selected *do* continue to exist even when scrolled far, far away, and even if the UI is virtualized. As soon as you unselect it and scroll again, they will be virtualized away as expected.  That's so you always have valid data for the selected item/node/list item, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented mvvm, I would suggest using interaction triggers.

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Xaml:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<TreeView >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemATemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyNodeTitle}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AChildCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemBTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyNodeTitle}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BChildCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.Items>
        <TreeViewItem Header="AItemRootNode" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeAStuff}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemATemplate}"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="BItemRootNode" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeBStuff}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemBTemplate}"/>
    </TreeView.Items>
</TreeView>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ICommand _aChildCommand;
public ICommand AChildCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_aChildCommand == null)
            _aChildCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAChild);
        return _aChildCommand;
    }
}

private void OnAChild(object obj)
{
}
```

Comment: I think you have things backwards here.  There is only one command.. the standard Application.Open command.  I want the same command but different CommandBindings per TreeViewItem (and thus, by default, every child in the DataTemplate for it).  Plus, your way won't work at all for commands triggered by Keyboard Shortcuts as its the TreeViewItem that has the focus and thus is the source of the command, and you've set your binding below that so it won't ever be hit.